# iOS Training model with CreateML MLTextClassifier class unable to filter from JSON

Tags: ios, swift, swift-playground, createml

I’m facing an issue with `MLTextClassifier` class that is used to `CreateML` for text.

Below is code snippet:

```
import CreateML
import Foundation

let objURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/jayprakashdubey/Desktop/headlines.json")

// 1. Load data from a JSON file
guard let newsJsonFileContent = try? MLDataTable(contentsOf: objURL) else {
    exit(0)
}

// 2. Make a train-test split
let (training, testing) = newsJsonFileContent.randomSplit(by: 0.8, seed: 5)

print("training: \(training.description)")

// 3. Create the model
if let objNewsClassifier = try? MLTextClassifier(trainingData: training, textColumn: "title", labelColumn: "category") {

   . . . 
}  else {
    print("Failed while classifying News - MLTextClassifier")
}
```

**If condition always fails** in above code snippet.

Below is console logs of `playground`.

[image: Screenshot for console log]

Tried with *all solutions that were posted on Stackoverflow but none worked.*

*Note: I'm using Xcode v11.3.1.*

Below is JSON file structure:

```
[
  {
    "text":"New 13-inch MacBook Pro comes with 6K monitor support, Dolby Atmos playback",
    "category":"Technology"
  },
     . . .
  {
    "text":"Apple Watch ECG detects signs of coronary ischemia missed by hospital ECG",
    "category":"Technology"
  }
]
```

Any fix?

Comment: I tried the above code with different json file. It works fine. https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DRg6.png

Comment: @VinayakaSY: Can share JSON file?

Comment: Test my JSON file with online parser and it is showing valid JSON.

Comment: I have uploaded it in this path. Path : https://drive.google.com/file/d/10vWb2qXabHkfi7lex8dt_ijq80wHzNwn/view?usp=sharing

Comment: This works too. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QAue5u06339UQEPaezZZOTymYoT9EYBI/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @VinayakaSY : Thanks a lots buddy! It was mismatch between textColumn and labelColumn. Interchanged both of them and it worked.

Comment: @VinayakaSY: Athough I'm able to create Mlmodel but it gives incorrect result when used in Project i.e. if entered some long text then it gives 'text' instead of 'category'. May I know which version of Xcode you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an issue with **incorrect textColumn and labelColumn values**. Interchanged values of the two and it worked.

Below is code snippet:

```
// 3. Create the model
if let objNewsClassifier = try? MLTextClassifier(trainingData: training, textColumn: "category", labelColumn: "title") {

   . . . 
}
```